# Unable to connect to any servers',{'172.17.0.2:9042':ConnectionRefusedError(111,"Triedconnectingto[('172.17.0.2',9042)].Lasterror:Connection refused"}

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I am unable to connect Scylladb server. I want to connect to the ip address 127.0.0.1,port 9042,but while executing cqlsh. getting connection error. unable to connect any servers. pls anyone resolve this error

docker exec -it my-scylla cqlsh